# Vim CommandT Window Height

Tags: vim

I am using CommandT and when I use `<leader>`t, the window only starts with a partial set of directories shown, whereas I would prefer to have all of the directories show and/or files. I prefer that it takes up most of the height of vim, in the terminal, as possible. Is there anyway to make a change to CommandT? I have read the help but don't seem to see anything related to why I only see 10 results to start with instead of as many as the window can show. I have not changed any mappings or options for the plugin.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any reason for asking that question here rather than on the plugin's issue tracker?

Comment: I guess not if this is not a good place to try to get help. If this is not a good place to ask for help, let me know and I will delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has been changed by the commit "[Switch some defaults to more reasonable values](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/commit/b5ca645b279cabf010a3a98da60e334da36ff88b)".

Insert

```
let g:CommandTMaxHeight=0
```

into your .vimrc file. Just running this command after VIM has already started up did not work for me presumably because the Command-T ruby code makes a copy of this value when it starts up.

g:CommandTMaxHeight is defined as:

> The maximum height in lines the match window is allowed to expand to.
>   If set to 0, the window will occupy as much of the available space as
>   needed to show matching entries. (default: 15)

Run the VIM command

```
:help g:CommandTMaxHeight
```

for more details